# Exporting custom ES6 module and importing into another local project is always undefined or {}, in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I'm working with TypeScript 3.4.5 and Webpack 4.32.2 on Windows 10 through WSL.

I'm trying to create a local package of tools, which aggregates basic classes into an index file, where I export them. No matter how I export or import in the other projects, the imported classes are always either 'undefined' or an empty object '{}'.

I tried to both npm link this 'api-tools' package to another local project, and I also tried to just install it through package.json's file dependency method, ie: { "api-tools": "file:../api-tools" }, and in both scenarios the result is the same.

Here is the api-tools package's index file:

**index.ts:**

```
import RestAPI from './lib/RestAPI';
export { RestAPI };
```

Here is the RestAPI library:

**lib/RestAPI.ts:**

```
export default class RestAPI {
    handle(req, res) {}
}
```

In the consuming project, I am importing it like this:

```
import { RestAPI } from 'api-tools';
console.log(RestAPI);
```

but logging this object to the console shows it is undefined.

I've tried different syntaxes of exporting and importing, ie.:

```
// RestAPI.ts:
export class RestAPI { 
    handle() {}
}

// index.ts:
import { RestAPI } from './lib/RestAPI';
console.log(RestAPI);

exports = { 
    RestAPI: RestAPI
}
// also tried module.exports = {...}
```

Putting this console.log here shows that the exported RestAPI is defined correctly, with all of its properties. From here I try using it on the consuming projects in different ways:

```
// both give empty object {}
import * as RestAPI from 'api-tools';
import RestAPI from 'api-tools';

// gives undefined
import { RestAPI } from 'api-tools';

console.log(RestAPI);
```

These always give an empty object, otherwise it is undefined.

Could this just be a TypeScript/typings thing? Everything builds fine and the paths of the projects seem fine, both to the compiled index.js, and the index.d.ts types file that api-tools package.json defines.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "types": "build/src/index.d.ts",
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "build",
        "module": "es6",            // specifiy module code generation
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",         // specify ECMAScript target version
        "strict": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "types": [ "webpack-env", "node" ]
}
```

Could it possibly be some issue with doing this through WSL? Or Webpack even?

I also tried to publish the package to npm, and import it through the normal process of npm install, but same thing happens, which makes me think it might be something with my configuration or understanding of modules.

Thanks for any help, been trying to figure this out for too long :-].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Webpack doesn't handle exports by default, have to set it in the output config:

```
output: {
    library: 'api-tools',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In `index.ts`, try:

```
export { default as RestAPI } from './lib/RestAPI';
```

Comment: Gave it a shot as:
export default class RestAPI { }

// index.ts:
export { default as RestAPI } from './lib/RestAPI';

// in client:
import { RestAPI } from 'api-tools';

console.log(RestAPI);

... but alas it is still undefined in the client! If I log the RestAPI object in the index.ts file, I can see it is the full object, so seems the disconnect is between the module's index.ts export and the client import, but nothing seems to be working. I may try to migrate the code to my mac and see if it does the same there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact some problem while trying to use npm package as a lib via `npm link`. The culprit in my case was the duplicated dependencies on both projects - Project and Lib were importing the same modules. **Webpack fails silently here.**

Managed to fix it by adding `"externals"` to my webpack configration in the Lib to tell those packages will exist in the project

```
externals: {
    "pixi.js": "pixi.js",
    immer: "immer",
    redux: "redux",
    lodash: "lodash",
    gsap: "gsap",
  },
```